"find: ‘/proc/780/map_files’: Operation not permitted" While Configuring MS SQL Server on Ubuntu 20.04 via package manager
Configuring SQL Server...

This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Thu Jul 18 12:26:58 2024
The following diagnostic information is available:

Reason: 0x00000001
     Signal: SIGABRT - Aborted (6)
     Stack:
         IP        Function
         ---------------- --------------------------------------
         000056222bc177f1 std::\__1::bad_function_call::\~bad_function_call()+0x97191
         000056222bc171b6 std::\__1::bad_function_call::\~bad_function_call()+0x96b56
         000056222bc1673f std::\__1::bad_function_call::\~bad_function_call()+0x960df
         00007fd03d931520 \__sigaction+0x50
         00007fd03d9859fc pthread_kill+0x12c
         00007fd03d931476 raise+0x16
         00007fd03d9177f3 abort+0xd3
         000056222bbaefcb std::\__1::bad_function_call::\~bad_function_call()+0x2e96b
         000056222bc24d9a std::\__1::bad_function_call::\~bad_function_call()+0xa473a
    Process: 2721 - sqlservr
     Thread: 2935 (application thread 0x36c)
  Instance Id: 8a584c01-2033-41b6-a9c8-60a5a275df99
    Crash Id: 9fbb8bdc-6c34-4a30-b20b-14823db6afb7
  Build stamp: 9da4a512b2a09348c40cfe9ff7f072a7fa572ee5a1a90da8524b94fc4dd72186
  Distribution: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
   Processors: 56
  Total Memory: 4294967296 bytes
   Timestamp: Thu Jul 18 12:26:58 2024
   Last errno: 2
Last errno text: No such file or directory
Capturing a dump of 2721
Successfully captured dump: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.7_18_2024_12_26_58.2721
Executing: /opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh with parameters
   handle-crash.sh
   /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
   2721
   /opt/mssql/bin
   /var/opt/mssql/log/

8a584c01-2033-41b6-a9c8-60a5a275df99
   9fbb8bdc-6c34-4a30-b20b-14823db6afb7

/var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.7_18_2024_12_26_58.2721

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Capturing core dump and information to /var/opt/mssql/log...
find: ‘/proc/2721/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/2721/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/2721/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/2721/map_files’: Operation not permitted
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
   Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
   Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
   Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
   Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
tail: cannot open '/var/log/syslog' for reading: Permission denied
Thu Jul 18 12:27:11 SAST 2024 Capturing program information
Dump already generated: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.7_18_2024_12_26_58.2721, moving to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.2721.temp/core.sqlservr.2721.gdmp
Moving logs to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.2721.temp/log/paldumper-debug.log
Thu Jul 18 12:27:12 SAST 2024 Capturing program binaries
Thu Jul 18 12:27:13 SAST 2024 Compressing the dump files
Core dump and information are being compressed in the background. When
complete, they can be found in the following location:
 /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.07_18_2024_12_27_06.2721.tbz2
Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG
in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.

This is my first time encountering this error for all the times I've been installing MS SQL Server on Linux systems using package maanager. When configuring, the process should be flow smoothly, however, for some reason I was getting the error above. Tried the bits and pieces of fixes (though related to docker) I could find online of almost the same issue but all did not work. I had to rebuild my server but still got the same error.

That looks like an error associated with the crash reporting, rather than anything related to the crash itself

sudo usermod -aG mssql $USER
Turns out this is all I had to. Problem gone!
